# PHP based boolean search for associative array

Tags: php

I have a associative array list where I need some boolean search in pure PHP. So i am struggle with getting matched data based on boolean search string

**Boolean Search String And Array List**

```
server_name = 'xxx'
AND
migration_start_date BETWEEN '2018/01/31' AND '2018/03/10'
AND
    (
       migration _scope = 'in scope' OR zones IN('warning')
       OR
       (status IS NOT NULL AND pre_check != 'pass' )
    )


Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [server_name] => xxx
        [migration_start_date] => 2018/01/31
        [migration_scope] => in scope
        [status] => planning
        [pre_check] => fail
        [zone] => warning
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [server_name] => xxx
        [migration_start_date] => 2018/01/31
        [migration_scope] => in scope
        [status] => completed
        [pre_check] => pass
        [zone] => removed
    )
)
```

Comment: Clarify for me what your boolean key is?

Comment: Have you looked at array_filter()? Or at any implementations of LINQ for PHP?